# windows phone 8 background agent can't listen Obscured and Unobscured event in some scenario

Tags: windows-phone-8, listen, background-agent

I have a background agent running in background that can listen to Unobscured event. But if I pressed home key then lock the device, my background agent can't receive obscured and Unobscured events anymore. Even if I implemented necessary location tracking APIs, it is not working as well. Any suggestion?

Comment: maybe because, background agent works once every 30 minutes(if you have enough battery)

Comment: When device is unlocked to tile screen, the unobsecured event isn't received as well. It seems that it has to be foreground app in order to get the event. Is this true?